# PHP Regex exclude Any character Custom Query

Tags: php, mysql, regex, wordpress

I'm using a database merging utility for wordpress called Mergebot.  One of the tools it includes, is Query Exclusion. This basically excludes certain db queries from being tracked.

I have to use PHP regex to identify the data I'd like to exclude . Example from the docs:

> For example let’s say you want to exclude a plugin’s settings from the options table in WordPress (that has the option_name "my_custom_plugin"). The field values would be as follows:
>
> Table: options
>
> Column: option_name
>
> Search: my_custom_plugin

I need to exclude any queries that affect the mm_sessions table, which uses the column `id` as the primary key.  So my current exclusion (which isn't working) looks like this:

> Table:  sessions
>
> Column:  id
>
> Search: [\s\S]

Example query that should be excluded:

```
UPDATE `mm_sessions` SET `data` = 'YToxOntzOjEwOiJtbV9wcmV2aWV3IjtzOjQxOTA6Ik86MTA6Ik1NX1ByZXZpZXciOjU6e3M6MjI6IgBNTV9QcmV2aWV3AGFjY2Vzc1RhZ3MiO2E6MDp7fXM6MTY6IgBNTV9QcmV2aWV3AHVzZXIiO086NzoiTU1fVXNlciI6NzY6e3M6MjE6IgBNTV9Vc2VyAG1lbWJlcnNoaXBJZCI7aToxO3M6MTU6IgBNTV9Vc2VyAHN0YXR1cyI7czoxOiIxIjtzOjIyOiIATU1fVXNlcgBwZW5kaW5nU3RhdHVzIjtzOjE6IjAiO3M6MjE6IgBNTV9Vc2VyAGltcG9ydGVkRmxhZyI7czoxOiIwIjtzOjI0OiIATU1fVXNlcgBsYXN0VXBkYXRlZERhdGUiO047czoyNjoiAE1NX1VzZXIAc3RhdHVzVXBkYXRlZERhdGUiO047czoyMjoiAE1NX1VzZXIAc3RhdHVzTWVzc2FnZSI7czowOiIiO3M6MjM6IgBNTV9Vc2VyAGRheXNDYWxjTWV0aG9kIjtzOjk6ImpvaW5fZGF0ZSI7czoyMjoiAE1NX1VzZXIAZGF5c0NhbGNWYWx1ZSI7czowOiIiO3M6MjU6IgBNTV9Vc2VyAGJlY2FtZUFjdGl2ZURhdGUiO047czoxNDoiAE1NX1VzZXIAcGhvbmUiO3M6MTQ6Iig1NTUpIDU1NS01NTU1IjtzOjE3OiIATU1fVXNlcgB1c2VybmFtZSI7czoxNDoic2FtcGxldXNlcm5hbWUiO3M6MTQ6IgBNTV9Vc2VyAGVtYWlsIjtzOjE1OiJzYW1wbGVAdGVzdC5jb20iO3M6MTg6IgBNTV9Vc2VyAGZpcnN0TmFtZSI7czo1OiJBZG1pbiI7czoxNzoiAE1NX1VzZXIAbGFzdE5hbWUiO3M6NDoiVGVzdCI7czoyNToiAE1NX1VzZXIAcmVnaXN0cmF0aW9uRGF0ZSI7czoxOToiMjAxNi0xMC0wMiAwMDozODo1NCI7czoyNToiAE1NX1VzZXIAY2FuY2VsbGF0aW9uRGF0ZSI7TjtzOjIzOiIATU1fVXNlcgBleHBpcmF0aW9uRGF0ZSI7TjtzOjE0OiIATU1fVXNlcgBub3RlcyI7czowOiIiO3M6MjU6IgBNTV9Vc2VyAHN1YnNjcmliZWRMaXN0SWQiO3M6MDoiIjtzOjI5OiIATU1fVXNlcgBzdWJzY3JpYmVkUHJvdmlkZXJJZCI7czowOiIiO3M6MjI6IgBNTV9Vc2VyAGxhc3RMb2dpbkRhdGUiO047czoyNzoiAE1NX1VzZXIAbGFzdExvZ2luSXBBZGRyZXNzIjtzOjA6IiI7czoxOToiAE1NX1VzZXIAbG9naW5Db3VudCI7aTotMTtzOjI0OiIATU1fVXNlcgBwYWdlQWNjZXNzQ291bnQiO2k6LTE7czoxOToiAE1NX1VzZXIAZW1haWxDb3VudCI7aTotMTtzOjI5OiIATU1fVXNlcgB3ZWxjb21lRW1haWxTZW50RGF0ZSI7TjtzOjIzOiIATU1fVXNlcgBiaWxsaW5nQWRkcmVzcyI7czoxMjoiMTIzIEZha2UgU3QuIjtzOjIwOiIATU1fVXNlcgBiaWxsaW5nQ2l0eSI7czo3OiJOb3doZXJlIjtzOjIxOiIATU1fVXNlcgBiaWxsaW5nU3RhdGUiO3M6MjoiVFgiO3M6MTk6IgBNTV9Vc2VyAGJpbGxpbmdaaXAiO3M6NToiNTU1NTUiO3M6MjM6IgBNTV9Vc2VyAGJpbGxpbmdDb3VudHJ5IjtzOjI6IlVTIjtzOjI0OiIATU1fVXNlcgBzaGlwcGluZ0FkZHJlc3MiO3M6MTI6IjEyMyBGYWtlIFN0LiI7czoyMToiAE1NX1VzZXIAc2hpcHBpbmdDaXR5IjtzOjc6Ik5vd2hlcmUiO3M6MjI6IgBNTV9Vc2VyAHNoaXBwaW5nU3RhdGUiO3M6MjoiVFgiO3M6MjA6IgBNTV9Vc2VyAHNoaXBwaW5nWmlwIjtzOjU6IjU1NTU1IjtzOjI0OiIATU1fVXNlcgBzaGlwcGluZ0NvdW50cnkiO3M6MjoiVVMiO3M6MjI6IgBNTV9Vc2VyAHRvdGFsUGF5bWVudHMiO2k6MDtzOjIxOiIATU1fVXNlcgB0b3RhbFJlZnVuZHMiO2k6MDtzOjI3OiIATU1fVXNlcgBmb3Jnb3RQYXNzd29yZEhhc2giO047czoxOToiAE1NX1VzZXIAbWVtYmVyc2hpcCI7TzoxODoiTU1fTWVtYmVyc2hpcExldmVsIjoyMzp7czozMjoiAE1NX01lbWJlcnNoaXBMZXZlbABlbWFpbFN1YmplY3QiO3M6MDoiIjtzOjI5OiIATU1fTWVtYmVyc2hpcExldmVsAGVtYWlsQm9keSI7czowOiIiO3M6MzI6IgBNTV9NZW1iZXJzaGlwTGV2ZWwAcmVmZXJlbmNlS2V5IjtzOjA6IiI7czoyNDoiAE1NX01lbWJlcnNoaXBMZXZlbABuYW1lIjtzOjA6IiI7czozNjoiAE1NX01lbWJlcnNoaXBMZXZlbABkZWZhdWx0UHJvZHVjdElkIjtzOjA6IiI7czozMDoiAE1NX01lbWJlcnNoaXBMZXZlbABpc0ZyZWVGbGFnIjtzOjE6IjEiO3M6MzM6IgBNTV9NZW1iZXJzaGlwTGV2ZWwAaXNEZWZhdWx0RmxhZyI7czoxOiIwIjtzOjMxOiIATU1fTWVtYmVyc2hpcExldmVsAGRlc2NyaXB0aW9uIjtzOjA6IiI7czozMDoiAE1NX01lbWJlcnNoaXBMZXZlbABwcm9kdWN0SWRzIjthOjA6e31zOjM0OiIATU1fTWVtYmVyc2hpcExldmVsAGxhc3RQcm9kdWN0SWRzIjthOjA6e31zOjMxOiIATU1fTWVtYmVyc2hpcExldmVsAGNhdGVnb3J5SWRzIjthOjA6e31zOjI2OiIATU1fTWVtYmVyc2hpcExldmVsAHN0YXR1cyI7czoxOiIxIjtzOjMxOiIATU1fTWVtYmVyc2hpcExldmVsAGVtYWlsRnJvbUlkIjtzOjA6IiI7czoyNzoiAE1NX01lbWJlcnNoaXBMZXZlbABidW5kbGVzIjtzOjA6IiI7czoyNzoiAE1NX01lbWJlcnNoaXBMZXZlbABleHBpcmVzIjtzOjE6IjAiO3M6MzI6IgBNTV9NZW1iZXJzaGlwTGV2ZWwAZXhwaXJlQW1vdW50IjtzOjA6IiI7czozMjoiAE1NX01lbWJlcnNoaXBMZXZlbABleHBpcmVQZXJpb2QiO3M6MDoiIjtzOjM5OiIATU1fTWVtYmVyc2hpcExldmVsAHdlbGNvbWVFbWFpbEVuYWJsZWQiO3M6MToiMSI7czoyNjoiAE1NX01lbWJlcnNoaXBMZXZlbAB3cFJvbGUiO3M6MTQ6Im1tLWlnbm9yZS1yb2xlIjtzOjU6IgAqAGlkIjtpOjA7czoxNjoiAE1NX0VudGl0eQB2YWxpZCI7YjowO3M6MTg6IgBNTV9FbnRpdHkAYXV0aEtleSI7czowOiIiO3M6MTc6IgAqAG5vdGlmeVNlcnZpY2VzIjtiOjE7fXM6MjU6IgBNTV9Vc2VyAGxhc3RNZW1iZXJzaGlwSWQiO3M6MDoiIjtzOjI3OiIATU1fVXNlcgBsYXN0TWVtYmVyc2hpcE5hbWUiO3M6MDoiIjtzOjI3OiIATU1fVXNlcgBsYXN0RGF5c0NhbGNNZXRob2QiO3M6MDoiIjtzOjI2OiIATU1fVXNlcgBsYXN0RGF5c0NhbGNWYWx1ZSI7czowOiIiO3M6Mjk6IgBNTV9Vc2VyAGxhc3RDYW5jZWxsYXRpb25EYXRlIjtzOjA6IiI7czoyNzoiAE1NX1VzZXIAbGFzdEV4cGlyYXRpb25EYXRlIjtzOjA6IiI7czoyMjoiAE1NX1VzZXIAbGFzdEZpcnN0TmFtZSI7czowOiIiO3M6MjE6IgBNTV9Vc2VyAGxhc3RMYXN0TmFtZSI7czowOiIiO3M6MTg6IgBNTV9Vc2VyAGxhc3RFbWFpbCI7czoyNjoiYWRtaW5Ac3BvcnRzYmV0dGluZ21heC5jb20iO3M6MjE6IgBNTV9Vc2VyAGxhc3RVc2VybmFtZSI7czoyNjoiYWRtaW5Ac3BvcnRzYmV0dGluZ21heC5jb20iO3M6MTg6IgBNTV9Vc2VyAGxhc3RQaG9uZSI7czowOiIiO3M6MTg6IgBNTV9Vc2VyAGxhc3ROb3RlcyI7czowOiIiO3M6MTk6IgBNTV9Vc2VyAGxhc3RTdGF0dXMiO3M6MDoiIjtzOjIzOiIATU1fVXNlcgBsYXN0U3RhdHVzTmFtZSI7czowOiIiO3M6Mjc6IgBNTV9Vc2VyAGxhc3RCaWxsaW5nQWRkcmVzcyI7czowOiIiO3M6MjQ6IgBNTV9Vc2VyAGxhc3RCaWxsaW5nQ2l0eSI7czowOiIiO3M6MjU6IgBNTV9Vc2VyAGxhc3RCaWxsaW5nU3RhdGUiO3M6MDoiIjtzOjIzOiIATU1fVXNlcgBsYXN0QmlsbGluZ1ppcCI7czowOiIiO3M6Mjc6IgBNTV9Vc2VyAGxhc3RCaWxsaW5nQ291bnRyeSI7czowOiIiO3M6Mjg6IgBNTV9Vc2VyAGxhc3RTaGlwcGluZ0FkZHJlc3MiO3M6MDoiIjtzOjI1OiIATU1fVXNlcgBsYXN0U2hpcHBpbmdDaXR5IjtzOjA6IiI7czoyNjoiAE1NX1VzZXIAbGFzdFNoaXBwaW5nU3RhdGUiO3M6MDoiIjtzOjI0OiIATU1fVXNlcgBsYXN0U2hpcHBpbmdaaXAiO3M6MDoiIjtzOjI4OiIATU1fVXNlcgBsYXN0U2hpcHBpbmdDb3VudHJ5IjtzOjA6IiI7czoyMjoiAE1NX1VzZXIAc3RhdHVzVXBkYXRlZCI7YjowO3M6Mjk6IgBNTV9Vc2VyAHNlbmRXZWxjb21lRW1haWxGbGFnIjtiOjE7czozNToiAE1NX1VzZXIAbWVtYmVyc2hpcExldmVsQ2hhbmdlZEZsYWciO2I6MTtzOjMxOiIATU1fVXNlcgBsYXN0Rm9yZ290UGFzc3dvcmRIYXNoIjtOO3M6MjY6IgBNTV9Vc2VyAG9yaWdpbkFmZmlsaWF0ZUlkIjtzOjA6IiI7czoyOToiAE1NX1VzZXIAb3JpZ2luU3ViYWZmaWxpYXRlSWQiO3M6MDoiIjtzOjIwOiIATU1fVXNlcgBpc0NTVkltcG9ydCI7YjowO3M6NToiACoAaWQiO2k6MTc2O3M6MTY6IgBNTV9FbnRpdHkAdmFsaWQiO2I6MTtzOjE4OiIATU1fRW50aXR5AGF1dGhLZXkiO3M6MDoiIjtzOjE3OiIAKgBub3RpZnlTZXJ2aWNlcyI7YjoxO31zOjE2OiIATU1fUHJldmlldwBkYXlzIjtpOjA7czoyNDoiAE1NX1ByZXZpZXcAbWVtYmVyVHlwZUlkIjtpOjA7czoyODoiAE1NX1ByZXZpZXcAYWNjZXNzVGFnQXBwbGllZCI7Tjt9Ijt9', `ip_address` = '127.0.0.1', `expiration_date` = '2016-12-20 18:50:19' WHERE `id` = '4b9cde7778be602befd455f194c38d44';
```

I believe the issue i'm encountering has to do with how I'm applying the regex syntax as it relates to the data in the db columns.  Any ideas on how to properly format the regex so it identifies if any characters exist in the ID column, then exclude that query?

EDIT:  I should also add that the docs specifically state to not include the table prefix when adding the exclusion; hence me using `sessions` instead of `mm_sessions`

Comment: I would contact support at Delicious Brains. This software is also currently in Beta so there may be an issue with the product itself.

Comment: Yeah, i tried that. Developers are unresponsive.  I figured being that it was  paid beta, they'd offer some support but no luck so far.